# Updating Python dict at the time of initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

I was just playing around with Python's **dictionaries** and **lists**. And I found these weird things -

At the time of initialization of any **Python dict, list** or some other data types, you can't perform operations of that data type.

```py
# Case 1
d1 = {}
d1.update({'a': 'A'})
print(d1)

# Case 2
d2 = {}.update({'p': 'P'})
print(d2)
```

Output:

```py
{'a': 'A'}
None
```

The weird thing is, neither d2 initialized not it threw any error.

### What I think about this?

Well, "Python's interpreter reads code line by line". So, when it reads the line `d1 = {}` it saves d1 and it's type (`dict`) in memory.

But this is not happening with `d2 = {}.update({'p': 'P'})`

Any operation of dict can be performed on dict object, which in the second case never initiated, ie. **dictionary object was never created**.

### What you think about this?

Please drop your answers and correct me, if I was wrong. Which I guess, I may be.

Comment: Please refer to the applicable documentation before posting here.
`update` alters the invoking object, in place, and returns `None`.
Your two examples are not functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict.update()` is an operation which has no return type.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `.update()` does the dictionary update in place and returns nothing, so when you are initiaising an empty dictionary and updating it, it returns Nothing and None gets assigned to the `d2`. Instead it will be like:

```
d = {}
d.update({'p': 'P'})
print(d)
```